# Doctrine2 DQL select on a resultset (double group by)

Tags: doctrine-orm, dql, query-builder

I have a complex query that need to be written in DQL / Doctrine2.
The pseudo query (I left out all the extra joins / calculations) is:

```
SELECT 
    a, SUM(b)
FROM (
    SELECT 
        a, SUM(b)
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY a,c    
) calc
GROUP BY a
```

First a group by on column a and c, and a select with again a group by on a afterwards.

The (pseudo) code on the select part is easy in querybuilder:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
$queryBuilder
    ->select(array('tbl'))
    ->addSelect('SUM(tbl.b)')
    ->from('\Model\MyModel', 'tbl')
    ->groupBy('a')
    ->addGroupBy('c');
$query = $queryBuilder->getQuery();
$results = $query->getResult();
```

However, how do I query this result again?
Is this possible?
Or can I somehow put them togheter in 1 queryBuilder object?